# Install spark 2.6.3

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. When I try to run spark 2.6.3 I get up the next error:

```
admini@localhost:~/Spark$ sh starter 
Preparing JRE ...
starter: 150: starter: bin/unpack200: not found
Error unpacking jar files. Aborting.
You might need administrative priviledges for this operation.
```

in version 11.10 running smoothly. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: I think you need to be root to run that. try sudo -s your password then run the script

Answer (score 4):

If you are using 64bit Ubuntu you need to install the [ia32-libs [image: Install ia32-libs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs) library that the spark for work, to install in a terminal type
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
restart the system and finally enter the directory where you installed Spark and the necessary permissions to read and execution totos users I gave permission
`sudo chmod 777 Spark`
but the permissions you see fit. Worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after installing openjdk-6-jre:i386 and icedtea plugin (but I don't know if that's really necessary)

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran this and it helped me:

```
mv jre jre.not sed -i 's/\/lib\/windows/\/lib\/linux/g' Spark/Spark
```

See http://dogma.swiftspirit.co.za/archives/tag/jre.